# Troubleshooting Script: Want to see command output to CLI

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a script for converting Handbrake videos, but I want to make presets. I am having trouble with the script, in the end it outputs something like

```
    HandBrakeCLI -i file.avi -o file.mp4 flags
```

But I can't get the flags part to work, so to troubleshoot I want to see what the command line is receiving as a translation of my script.

Here is the link to my working script

[How to Install Handbrake and Convert recursive file tree's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644313/how-to-install-handbrake-and-convert-recursive-file-trees)

Here is what I would like it to look like

*Only the changes are shown*

```
    FLAGS="-E ac3 -6 5point1 -R 48 -B 448 --audio-fallback ac3"
    if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
        TRANSCODEDIR="."
    else
        TRANSCODEDIR="$1"
    fi
        find "$TRANSCODEDIR"/* -type f -exec bash -c 'HandBrakeCLI -i "$1" -o "${1%\.*}".mp4 "$FLAGS"' __ {} \;
```

Basically the $Flags option isnt working, and as I mess around it either doesn't find the file, or does and doesn't see the flags, help with the script is fine, but for future debugging of other scripts i wouldnt mind knowing how to just output the commands it "would" have sent to the shell instead just to the screen or a text file probably is better.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to export `PRESET`, or `FLAGS`. Otherwise it won't affect child processes like the new bash commands run by `find`.

Comment: I tried export Flags to no avail, could you give me the line to export flags to the child process?

Comment: Where did you put `export FLAGS`? I'd just change line 1 to `export FLAGS="-E ...`.

Comment: So I did this.. export FLAGS="-E ac3"
exec "$@" and when I exit out back to shell and tpye FLAGS it says -E is not a known command, does that mean its not getting past -E or that is all the is getting exported

Comment: O.o I don't understand what you did. DId you try to run `FLAGS`? WHere did `exec "$@"` come from?

Comment: exec "$@" came from another guide, and yes I just tried to run flags to see what got exported

Comment: If you want to see what `FLAGS` contains, do `echo "$FLAGS"`.

Comment: should that work in my main shell after script failes/stops? As of now its empty..

Comment: No, scripts cannot affect parent shells.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25897/discussion-between-donuts-server-and-muru).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `set -x` to the top of your bash script or (equivalently) run it using

```
 bash -x yourscript
```

See `help set` or the `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` section of `man bash`:

```
  -x  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.
```

There is more discussion at [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script) on [SE Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

---

What you will probably see in this case is that `$FLAGS` variable is empty: it is enclosed in single quotes so gets passed literally to the `bash -c` subshell, where `$FLAGS` is undefined.

Comment: I already tried bash -x it gives me kinda the same verbose info handbrake would, im basically looking for a translation of my variables, because I suspect as you do, that its not being exported

Answer (score 0):

```
export FLAGS="-f mp4 -O --decomb=bob --loose-anamorphic --modulus 2 -e x264 -q 20 --vfr -E ac3 -6 5point1 -R 48 -B 448 --audio-fallback ac3 --encoder-preset=veryfast  --verbose=1"
```

Worked for me, thanks for the help guys, see the script in action at [How to Install Handbrake and Convert recursive file tree's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644313/how-to-install-handbrake-and-convert-recursive-file-trees)