# Help troubleshooting Variable in simple script

Tags: scripts, environment-variables, find

So i have this script here [Remove Audio Streams of videos - recursively without converting audio or video with FFMPEG](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660827/remove-audio-streams-of-videos-recursively-without-converting-audio-or-video-w/660828#660828) But the subtitles part doesn't work. Currently I have tried a few variations of

```
export FLAGS='-sub_charenc CP1252 -i "${1%\.*}".srt -vcodec copy -acodec copy'
```

and

```
find "$TRANSCODEDIR"/* -type f -name "*.mkv" -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$1" "$FLAGS" "${1%\.*}".mkv ' _ {} \;
```

But I am getting errors like movie.mkv.srt does not exist or atleast one output file must be specified, and others, I am going to trial and error again and keep notes of what errors I get depending on what variation, but any help pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.

What code is supposed to do

File Tree Example

Movie.mkv
Movie2.mkv
Movie.srt
Movie2.srt

It should add the correct srt to the correct mkv.

As it stands the error i get is that

```
Unrecognized option 'sub_charenc CP1252 -i "${1%\.*}".srt -vcodec copy -acodec c                                                                                                             opy'.
```

Comment: this is a hard to properly explain question and badly worded, but I will show my answer, as I have figured it out via trial and error... lots of trail and error

Comment: I shouldn't say I have it figured out, as I think its impossible, but I came to the solution of making it a one liner.... see below comments

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a script with the name `export_flags`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   srt_file_name="${1%\.*}".srt
   if [ -f "$srt_file_name" ]; then
           FLAGS="-i $srt_file_name -sub_charenc CP1252 -vcodec copy -acodec copy"
   else
           FLAGS=""
   fi
   export FLAGS="$FLAGS"
   ```
2. Make it executable

   ```
   chmod +x export_flags
   ```
3. Start a test with

   ```
   source export_flags your_mkv
   echo $FLAGS
   ```

   E.G.

   ```
   source export_flags SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mkv
   echo $FLAGS
   ```

   the output should be something like this

   ```
   -i SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.srt -sub_charenc CP1252 -vcodec copy -acodec copy
   ```
4. Use four `find` command

   ```
   find . -type f -name "*.mkv" -exec bash -c 'source export_flags "$1"; ffmpeg -i "$1" $FLAGS "${1%\.*}".mkv' _ {} \;
   ```

   In my case I have this

   ```
   ffmpeg version 2.5.8-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
     built with gcc 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13)
     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.15.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libxvid --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libsoxr --enable-gnutls --enable-openal --enable-libopencv --enable-librtmp --enable-libx265
     libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
     libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
     libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
     libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
     libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
     libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
     libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
     libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
     libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
   Input #0, matroska,webm, from './SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mkv':
     Metadata:
       ENCODER         : Lavf56.15.102
     Duration: 00:00:00.32, start: 0.080000, bitrate: 2642 kb/s
       Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
       Metadata:
         ENCODER         : Lavc56.13.100 libx264
       Stream #0:1: Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp (default)
       Metadata:
         ENCODER         : Lavc56.13.100 libvorbis
   Input #1, srt, from './SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.srt':
     Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
       Stream #1:0: Subtitle: subrip
   File './SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mkv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N]
   ```

Comment: long story short I had trouble properly escaping the double quotes inside the variable FLAGS, the script works now, i just made one liners, but I would like to remove the ADD SUBTITLES lines, and make them into uncommentable FLAGS, just to keep it uniform, its hard to explain, so if you want, take a look at the linked script and it should make sense what I mean

Comment: updated to what you said, no luck, its not translating the "${1%\.*}".srt inside the flag, If I remove the quotes around the export Flags=whatever instead of export FLAGS="whatever", then it says at least one output must be specified, IE: its not translating the "${1%\.*}".mkv

Comment: I don't think what I want is possible, the same line for stripping audio, and for adding subtitles, as the subtitles line would require the exported variable FLAGS to have "${1%\.*}".srt  expanded, but its exported before it can even do that, and if it could, I dont think it could re-expand it each time to the next item, the idea is recursive converting

Comment: I will check this.

Comment: Done, it should work now.

Comment: Im not looking to add more lines to the FIND line of my script or have a seperate file as that makes the script non-portable, I did create a question at Stack Overflow with a better layout of the question perhaps you could look [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32089462/exporting-a-variable-with-a-variable-inside-the-relys-on-a-find-statement)