# Edit find command to exclude a file

Tags: command-line, find

So I made this script [Convert videos recursively with handbrake](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644313/how-to-install-handbrake-and-convert-recursive-file-trees).

And it uses this command as an option

```
find . -name '*.mkv' -exec rm -r {} \;
```

But i made this new script, for removing audio streams recursively [Remove Audio Streams of videos - recursively without converting audio or video with FFMPEG](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660827/remove-audio-streams-of-videos-recursively-without-converting-audio-or-video-w)

But I would like to add the option to remove all `*.mkv` files EXCEPT ones that are `*FINAL.mkv` as that is the output my second script uses for the files.

Could somebody help real quick, I'm not very good at coding, I can just manipulate it very well and understand it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove all `mkv` files recursively except `FINAL.mkv` you can do :

```
find . -type f -not -name '*FINAL.mkv' -name '*.mkv' -delete
```

- Use `-type f` to search for only files
- `-name '*.mkv'` will get us all `.mkv` files
- `-not -name '*FINAL.mkv'` will leave out all the `*FINAL.mkv` files
- `-delete` will remove the files found.

Also do a dry run by the following at first to check that everything is all right :

```
find . -type f -not -name 'FINAL.mkv' -name '*.mkv'
```

Comment: can I ask why the code I found uses -exec rm -r {} \; instead of -delete?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers thats a clumsy way of doing what `-delete` does, also `-r` is redundant with `rm` as we are dealing with files only..`-exec rm -r {} \;` will spawn an extra process `rm` for every file, it will be a improvement of `-exec rm -r {} \;` if `-exec rm {} +` was being used..

Comment: and to sum up your previous comment altho -exec rm {} + is an improvement, i am better off using -delete anyway

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Yeah..i did not look the `*FINAL.mkv` glob you wanted..fixed..

Comment: would it be to much to ask for second bit of code that renamed all remaining files the same name without the word FINAL?, I can give you credit in the script im creating for the help with the perfections, im all about automation, but I can start a new thread or research more if not.

Comment: Im assuming there is only the files wanting to be renamed, not extra files that need to be ignored, say just a folder with 1 season of episodes, now renamed *FINAL.mkv that i want to revert to *.mkv after removing original files

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers I would love to help but i don't think i get this one properly..could you please ask a new question with more details (and examples)..

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/660839/rename-final-mkv-to-mkv-keeping-original