# Rename *FINAL.mkv to *.mkv keeping original "*"

Tags: scripts, rename

So I have a bunch of files created with the name *FINAL.mkv and I have a (1st) script to remove all the files except files with FINAL.mkv

I need help renaming the new files back to the original *.mkv, any help appreciated!

Example file tree:

```
Stargate.mkv

StargateFINAL.mkv
```

Now after 1st script

```
StargateFINAL.mkv
```

What I want to end up with (this is in regard to recursive converting of videos)

```
Stargate.mkv
```

Comment: once answered perhaps the question can be re-worded to better help others

Comment: Please add some examples of the current file names and your desired names from them ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the word `FINAL` comes only once in the filenames, you can do:

```
rename -n 's/FINAL//' *.mkv
```

This will do the dry run. After being sure you can carry out the operation :

```
rename 's/FINAL//' *.mkv
```

Comment: That was fun, script is perfected, thanks! [Original Script heemayl helped with](http://askubuntu.com/questions/660827/remove-audio-streams-of-videos-recursively-without-converting-audio-or-video-w/660828#660828)